# Traversing through Multiple objects

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have 2 Custom Objects - **Package_Item__c**, and **Product__c**. **Package_Item__c** has two fields - **Quantity(Number)** and **Product(Lookup to Product__c)**. Is there any way I can access the **Package_Item__c.Quantity__c** field from a **Product__c** Object? Here is the code I tired

```
public List<Product__c> prodlist{get; set;}
prodlist = [SELECT Name,
                    (SELECT Package_Item__c.Quantity__c FROM Product__c.Package_Item__c)
                    FROM Product__c]
```

Also I have a datatable in VF page, where I have to access the Quantity values.  Here's what I tried -

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!prodlist}" var="p">
   <apex:column>
           <apex:inputField required="false" value="{!p.Package_Item__r.Quantity__c}"/>
   </apex:column>
</apex:datatable>
```

how can I access the quantity values in the inputfield?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Product__c getProduct() {
    return  [SELECT Name, 
      (SELECT Quantity__c FROM Package_Items__r)
        FROM Product__c WHERE Id = :someProductId][0];
}
```

and the VF dataTable is:

```
<apex:datatable value="{!product.Package_Items__r}" var="pi">
  <apex:inputField required="false" value="{!pi.Quantity__c}"/>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Reference: [Relationship queries in SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm)

Comment: This works, but only for one Record. I want to return a List of all the records, and changing the Apex code to a list gives me the runtime error - "Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Package_Items__r' Error is in expression '{!product.Package_Items__r}' in component <apex:dataTable> in page"

Comment: if you have multiple products, each with multiple packageItems that you want to display, then your VF page needs to be nested datatables. It is possible I don't understand your requirement and you should edit your OP to provide an example of the intended result. Please don't respond in a comment thread.